# Tabbed Activity with two fragments and a single button in container activity then how to get data from both the fragments

Tags: android

I have a Mainactivity which is a Tabbed activity that contains two fragments...
Both fragments contains form....
there is a single button in main activity .... 
now how can i get the form data from both the fragments by clicking on this button in main activity container?

Below is my main Activity that contains two tabs
each tabs has fragments which contain form to be filled
There is a registration button...

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.example.dellpc.eventsbox.EventDetails">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="@dimen/height"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        >



        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/profile_id"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:background="@drawable/akgec1"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            />
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/height_double"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"


            />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"

            android:layout_height="@dimen/height"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:tabTextColor="#607D8B"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>




</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>



<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/registerEventBTN"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:text="REGISTER ON THIS"
    android:background="#caE45a"
    >

</Button>
```

I Have created two fragment classes for the two forms and i am using SectionPageAdapter for connecting the fragment to the main container....

Problem :- The fragments doesnot contain any button...
the only button is in The container class ...
i want to use this button to get all data filled in both the fragment
but i am not getting the way to do this..
please help

Answer (score 0):

Make Model containing the variable you need. Set listeners on your views and pass the value/input from the user to your object/model using setters on both fragments. You have to implement interface which will pass your model from fragment to main activity which is hosting button. Make your model parcelable.